# Joining points in different graphs in groupplots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I (probably naïvely) wrote:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, calc, arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style = {group size = 1 by 2},
                width=9cm, height=4cm,
                xmin=0, xmax=20, 
                ymin=0, ymax=12,
                xlabel = {x},
                ylabel = {y},
                grid,
                /tikz/declare function = {r1(\x)=2*\x/10 - \x/800*\x;
                r2(\x)=2*\x - \x/10*\x;},
            ]
            \nextgroupplot[
            ]
            \addplot[ultra thick, red,  domain=0:10] {r2(x)};
            \addplot[thick, dotted, red,  domain=10:20, forget plot] {r2(x)};
            \node (A) at (5, {r2(5)}) {A}; 
            \nextgroupplot[
            ]

            \addplot[ultra thick, cyan,  domain=0:20] {r1(x)};
            \node (B) at (5, {r1(5)}) {B}; 
            % does not work:
            \draw [gray, ultra thick, ->] (A) -- (B);
        \end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and obtained:

[image: output]

I expected the arrow going from the upper graph to the lower one; clearly there is some offset needed here, but I was not able to find it.

Is it possible to mark the position in a graph *absolutely* so that I can reach it from another plot?

Comment: Move the `\draw` to after `\end{groupplot}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move

```
\draw [gray, ultra thick, ->] (A) -- (B);
```

to *after* `\end{groupplot}`, and it works fine.

(I don't know exactly what happens at a lower level, but it looks as though the start point of the arrow is the same you would get if node `A` was also in the second plot of the group.)

[image: working arrow]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, calc, arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style = {group size = 1 by 2},
                width=9cm, height=4cm,
                xmin=0, xmax=20, 
                ymin=0, ymax=12,
                xlabel = {x},
                ylabel = {y},
                grid,
                /tikz/declare function = {r1(\x)=2*\x/10 - \x/800*\x;
                r2(\x)=2*\x - \x/10*\x;},
            ]
            \nextgroupplot[
            ]
            \addplot[ultra thick, red,  domain=0:10] {r2(x)};
            \addplot[thick, dotted, red,  domain=10:20, forget plot] {r2(x)};
            \node (A) at (5, {r2(5)}) {A}; 
            \nextgroupplot[
            ]

            \addplot[ultra thick, cyan,  domain=0:20] {r1(x)};
            \node (B) at (5, {r1(5)}) {B}; 

        \end{groupplot}
        % it works down here
        \draw [gray, ultra thick, ->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```